# How to auto-scale a web application in Kubernetes without overprovisioning?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, autoscaling

Consider a traditional web application.

Under no load, the application does not require or utilize too many resources. The CPU usage grows linearly with the number of users/requests per second.

If I set the CPU request to a baseline value, something like 5%, then under the high load, the HorizontalPodAutoscaler just keep scheduling pods on the same node instead of triggering a Cluster Auto Scaler, even if the CPU usage of the node is over 90%. This leads to node and application becoming unstable and does not allow enough time for Cluster Auto Scaler to kick in and add capacity. What's worse is that with a bunch of microservices, each could be utilizing less than 5% but together they can overload a node.

I could set the CPU request to a higher value, something like 20% or 21%, basically not allowing more than 4 pods on the same node. This works fine for auto-scaling if you have only one deployment (after 84% the HPA would not be able to schedule another pod and trigger a Cluster Auto Scaler). However if your application consists of multiple micro-services, you are basically over-provisioning. If you want to perform a blue-green or a rolling update, you practically need to 2x (double) the amount resources, even under no load.

What am I missing? Is it possible to set up HPA, Cluster Auto Scaler and resource requests to ensure that the application can scale properly, and avoid over-provisioning at least 2x resources just for performing deployments?

Something that comes to mind is a cpu usage based toleration or an anti-affinity that would prevent from scheduling on a node with e.g. >70% CPU usage, but it does not seem obvious at all and I am unsure if that would even work with the Cluster Auto Scaler.

Comment: Are you using CPU limits? Profile the application how much it needs during peak traffic (without CPU limits set).